# geth ethereum client connect to ganache

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py, go-ethereum

I want to set up a private Ethereum Testnet on different computers within one network.

I have my private Computer with a working web3.py Implementation connected to a Ganachi Testnet. I can deploy Smart Contracts from a program written in python with solc compiler inside my program.

Now I want to set up two different other ethereum nodes on a VM and on a raspberry pi. I installed geth on the VM but I dont understand how to connect the VM with Ganache running on my computer.

Here is the setup:

RPC-Server Ganachi: http://127.0.0.1:7545 
Network ID = 5777

I tried this command to connect the geth node with the ganache:

> geth --port 5000 --networkid 5777 --rpc --rpcport 7545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcapi'eth,net,web3,personal' --testnet

It start running and write out this information 
...Starting peer-to-peer node 
...Allocated chache and file handles 
...Persisted trie from memory database 
...Initialised chain configuration 
...Initialising Ethereum protocol 
...New local node record 
...IPC endpoint opened 
...HTTP endpoint opened 
...Started P2P networking 
...New local node record

When i start my program nothing is shown on the VM and when i want to send a Transaction to the account i created on the VM i cant see another balance.

This is my code for the transaction on my local computer:

> w3.eth.sendTransaction({'from': '0xC4AEe6dBE1BF2461776f48a4Ca0E06E39dE08bB6', 'value': wei_value, 'to':               w3.toChecksumAddress('0xbdb3c3a7a0949b0aab9346e858f85fa8e3764733')})

The Transaction is done and the ether is withdrawn from the account in the ganache GUI.

But when i test the account on the VM with this code:

> geth --port 5000 --networkid 5777 --rpc --rpcport 7545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --testnet console

> eth.getBalance(w3.toChecksumAddress('0xbdb3c3a7a0949b0aab9346e858f85fa8e3764733')})

The Ouput is 0 !!!

Can someone help me to connect the VM geth with my computers Ganache ?

The VM and my Computer are connected through VPN. When i change the settings in Ganachi for example to http://0.0.0.0:7545 i get an error in my python code when i change the line:

> provider = HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545')

to

> provider = HTTPProvider('http://0.0.0.0:7545')

Following this error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=7545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000000004AC1128>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10049] Die angeforderte Adresse ist in diesem Kontext ungültig',))

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ganache simulates a local instance of Ethereum on your machine. It is meant for local development and is not compatible with your geth node. If you wanted to setup a local Ethereum network, you could setup a geth node on both your local machine and the VM, two geth nodes on your local machine, or two geth nodes on the VM.